# Can't call anonymous class method

Tags: java, class, closures

I can imagine some very creative code in Java:

```
Object thing = new Object() {
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Hi!");
    }
};
thing.speak();
```

Or even, to get the full closure effect, define a `Function` interface ... you get the idea?

Why doesn't this code work?

Comment: Because `speak()` is not declared on the type `Object`. You can use reflection if you _really_ want it.

Comment: @Sotirios said it.  After you construct it, 'thing' is still declared as just Object, so you have to adhere to that interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe you can do it like this :-

```
new Object() {    
     public void speak() {
        System.out.println("Hi!");
     }
}.speak();
```

may help you .

Comment: Why do you think this is any different than what OP has?

Comment: it prints "Hi !" as he would

Comment: Why do you think this is any **different** than what OP has?

Comment: I use the object directly without variable **thing**

Comment: You're still not explaining how that difference solves anything.

Comment: It compiles and runs, which is different from what the OP has. However, you still can't store it in a variable or field without at least first declaring an interface that includes the speak method.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the usefulness in this example, but some type of overriding method(s) on the original declaration is useful and because of it is overriding, you can call the methods.  Otherwise in your case, just use the reflection as:

```
thing.getClass().getMethod("speak").invoke(thing);
```

and for the overriding method:

```
Object thing = new Object() {
   public void toString() {
      System.out.println("Hi! Me inside your mind!");
      return "not today!";
   }
};
thing.toString();
```