# Methods of anonymous classes in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism, anonymous-class

Is there a way to capture the type of an anonymous class?

In the following example, how can i invoke the method `g2` of the anonymous class? can't think of a specific case that it would be absolutely useful. and i'm aware that anonymous classes are for "on-the-fly" use. however, wondering.

If i can't invoke it, what's the use of being able to define it (if any-- other than being a helper to other methods of the anonymous class itself) in the anonymous class?

```
// http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

public class SomeClass {

    abstract class HelloWorld {  abstract public void greet();  }

    public void sayHello() {        
        class EnglishGreeting extends HelloWorld {  //  local class 
            String name = "world";
            public void greet() {  System.out.println("Heya " );    }
            public void gg() { System.out.println("do this as well.. ");}  }  
        HelloWorld englishGreeting = new EnglishGreeting();

        HelloWorld frenchGreeting = new HelloWorld() {  //  anonymous class 
            public void g2() { System.out.println("do this too.. ");}
            public void greet() {  System.out.println("Salute ");  }
        };  


        englishGreeting.greet();
        ((EnglishGreeting)englishGreeting).gg();
        frenchGreeting.greet();
//        ((frenchGreeting.getClass())frenchGreeting).g2();  // gives a checked error
    }  

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SomeClass myApp = new SomeClass();
        myApp.sayHello(); 
}            
}
```

Note: saw [Can't call anonymous class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049634/cant-call-anonymous-class-method) & [Anonymous Inner Classes Inside Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950807/anonymous-inner-classes-inside-methods) along with some other relevant discussions.

TIA.

//==============================================

EDIT:

the below worked-- one step closer to it for whatever its worth. not looking up its reference type when the method is invoked right on the new object.

```
        HelloWorld frenchGreeting = new HelloWorld() {
            public HelloWorld g2() { System.out.println("do this too.. ");  return this; }
            public void greet() {  System.out.println("Salute ");  }
        }.g2();
```

Comment: As far as I know this can't be done, but why would you want to do this anyway? Why not create a real class with callable methods?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels read the second par-- the phrase with "wondering" in regard to "why".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call it directly, e.g.

```
new HelloWorld() {
    // ...
}.g2();
```

However, notice that you can't assign the variable and call it directly, and you can't call it elsewhere in the method. Still, this is the closest thing I could think of to answering your question.

Comment: yeah - I think that's the closest. can't capture the type of the anonym.class for any further use than getClass() does.

Answer (score 1):

no, you cannot call g2. actually, anonymous class in java serves as a short hand to implement an instance of an interface only used in one place. with specified interface, the method you want to be called should be specifically defined by that interface.

the reason to allow you define non-interface method is because designers considered the case when you want to implement helper method.

i think anonymous interface is widely used.

Comment: have you come across with a firm verification of this in Java docs?

Comment: @user3880721 you want a javadoc for what? you want this? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: @user3880721 A "firm verification" of what? That you can't call methods on a type, outside of that type, that aren't exposed by that type? `g2` is a `HelloWorld`.

Comment: It's worth noting that anonymous classes need not be declared as an *interface* implementation.  They can be declared as any non-primitive type, all the way up to `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to capture the type of an anonymous class?

No.  You can only access it for reflection.

> If i can't invoke it, what's the use of being able to define it (if any-- other than being a helper to other methods of the anonymous class itself) in the anonymous class?

Since they can only be referenced from within the anonymous type itself, they are of no use outside of it.  So, as you say, they may be used to organize the logic within the class, but that's about it.  The only exception is the edge case that @bcsb1001 describes, in which you invoke the method directly on the anonymous object creation expression (and not the variable to which it is assigned).

> the below worked...

That's because the type of the expression `new HelloWorld() { ... }` is the type of the anonymous class.  Since the creation expression has the actual anonymous class type, you can use it to access any members it declares.  However, since the class is *anonymous*, it has no name, so you cannot declare a variable of the concrete anonymous type.  The closest you can get is declaring a variable of `HelloWorld`.  Since the variable is declared as `HelloWorld`, you can only use it to access members declared on `HelloWorld` or one of its supertypes.

If Java added support for inferred types in declarations, you could write something like `var g = new HelloWorld() { ... };` (C# style) or `auto g = new HelloWorld() { ... };` (C++ style), and the type of `g` would be inferred from the assignment.  That would allow you to capture the anonymous type without needing a type name.  However, Java has no such capabilities at this time.